# Условия запроса INSERT

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysql

Имеется запрос

```
$sql="INSERT INTO pages (url,name) VALUES  ('$url','$name')";
```

Как составить условия что бы в таблицу не записывались одинаковые записи ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задайте паре полей url и name ключ UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

Выполни сначала

```
select count(*) from pages where url = '$url' and name = '$name'
```

Если вернет > 0, то

```
INSERT INTO pages (url,name) VALUES  ('$url','$name')";
```

не выполняешь.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO pages (url,name) VALUES  ('$url','$name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед вставкой вы можете делать проверку, есть ли у вас уже такая запись.
А вообще для таких случаев в базах данных существует понятие первичного ключа, который видимо не определен на вашей таблице.

Comment: Вообще то определен в поле id. Но хули толку, не делать же мне все поля первичным ключем если это вообще возможно.

Comment: Смотря что делать первичным ключем в вашем случае id возможно не нужен как первичный ключ, вам же необходима уникальность (name, url)
делаете ключ составной из данных полей и будет вам счастье

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сделать name и url первичным ключем??? Но ведь так нельзя.

Comment: Ну я не понимаю смысла ваших полей
Возможно просто можно было и name сделать первичным ключем.
Просто связка name, url может вам нагадить такими записями:
'hashcode', 'hashcode.ru'
'hashcode', 'hashcode.ru/bla-bla-bla'
'hashcode', 'hashcode.ru/bla-bla-bla-bla-bla'

Все зависит от того что вы собираетесь хранить, вопрос был задан обеспечить уникальность конкретно url, name
Мое мнение это первичный ключ на этих полях

А то что написано выше это уже мои догадки

Comment: Не первичный ключь нельзя сделать на обеих полях, здесь нужна проверка на сходство полей. Я себе это предстовляю как то так 

WHERE $url!=$_POST['url'] and $name!=$_POST['name']

Comment: Вы так считаете? 
Что нельзя?
Читайте документацию почаще.


CREATE TABLE
 newTable
 ( field1 INT(11)
 , field2 INT(11)
 , field3 VARCHAR(5)
 , field4 BLOB
 , PRIMARY KEY (field2, field1, field3)   <====
 )

Comment: @ЫЫЫ не первичный ключ, а уникальный ключ именно паре полей

Comment: А разве первичный ключ не является уникальным?

Comment: Первичный ключ является уникальным, но не наоборот. Уникальных ключей может быть несколько, первичный только один. И уникальный и первичный ключи могут состоять из нескольких полей. Использование естественных ключей почти всегда приводит к деградации производительности, усложнению структуры изменения данных, увеличению размеров индексов (и размер базы растет и скорость падает). При этом суррогатные ключи обладают большей гибкостью и не приводят к проблемам естественных ключей. Отдельным случаем являются развязочные таблицы, где первичный ключ может быть составным по делу.

Comment: Поэтому id - primary key. (name,url) - unique.

Answer (score 0):

Для верного ответа важен контекст данной задачи. Расскажу о том контексте, о котором подумал я.

Если тебе необходимо чтобы где либо (например, в отчете на сайте) не было дублей из-за этой таблицы, то данную задачу надо решать на том этапе, а не на этом. В данном контексте записывать в базу надо не задумываясь о дублях. Т.е. пишешь все подряд прямо так:

```
INSERT INTO pages (url,name) VALUES  ('$url','$name')";
```

А когда будешь извлекать, то фильтруй данные как хочешь, например:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PAGES;
```

Comment: Это вариант плохого проектирования БД. Не делайте так никогда.

Comment: Почему вы считаете это плохим вариантом проектирования?